Event Confirmation Message vs Event Confirmation Email: Ckeditor
There is no Ckeditor for an event "Confirmation Message" ( https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview%2Fparticipant&reset=1&action=add&context=participant&cid=204
) therefore the textarea contains a mix of text and html from a corresponding template and, unfortunately, emailed as such.
The same event "Confirmation Email"  ( https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fmanage%2Fregistration&reset=1&action=update&id=3 ) does have Ckeditor though.

Not a direct answer to your question but the extension "Custom Event Communication" may be useful - it provides an alternative way to send confirmation emails for CiviCRM Event: https://docs.civicrm.org/eventmessages/en/latest/

@Fabian That's great, thank you for the pointer! Wish this substituted event registration forms for administrators.

I have an extension that converts textarea field to Richtext for some fields,
Event confirmation is one of them, like to try?
https://github.com/pradpnayak/texttockeditor

THanks, much better than individual forms tackling. Have noticed  not all texts act the same, sometimes formatting gets stripped completely, sometimes html tags stays visible. Could it be because of Ckeditor4 being used?

yeah, its using from the config
